# `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together` when attempting to plot a univariate distribution from a DataFrame column using Seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot the univariate distribution of a column in a Pandas `DataFrame`. Here's the code:

```
ad = summary["Acquired Delay"]
sns.distplot(ad)
```

This throws:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (10,) (9,)
```

I've checked to see if there is anything wrong about this series, passing it as `ad.values`, but the same error occurs. The problem disappears when I use the `.plot` method of `ad`:

```
ad = summary["Acquired Delay"]
ad.plot.hist()
```

[image: Successful Plotting with matplotlib]

The problem disappears. The plot is less translucent, but reasonably good. Is this a common bug in seaborn? Has this happened because my data contained large number of zeros?

Comment: please include the full error traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: Also, please paste the output from running `print ad` or `print summary`.

Comment: Can't include print summary or print ad, because the series is far too long. The problem was that `ad` had a lot of zeros. 

Can't include full error traceback for the problem has been fixed by the fine folks who maintain seaborn!! pip install seaborn --upgrade doesn't work, we are still at seaborn 0.7.0.dev0. But the issue has been fixed on the [master](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn), i.e. the github repository.

Big cheers to @mwaskom!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the seaborn function `distplot` includes lines

```
   if bins is None:
        bins = min(_freedman_diaconis_bins(a), 50)
```

to set the number of bins when it's not specified, and the `_freedman_diaconis_bins` function can return a non-integer number if the length of `a` isn't square and the IQR is 0.  And if `a` is dominated by enough zeros, the IQR will be zero as well, e.g.

```
>>> sns.distributions.iqr([0]*8 + [1]*2)
0.0
```

so your intuition that the high number of zeros might be playing a role was right, I think.  Anyway, if we get a float number back for the number of bins, that will break `np.histogram`:

```
>>> np.histogram([0,0,1], bins=2)
(array([2, 1], dtype=int32), array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ]))
>>> np.histogram([0,0,1], bins=2.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-9aae3e6c77af>", line 1, in <module>
    np.histogram([0,0,1], bins=2.1)
  File "/home/dsm/sys/pys/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 249, in histogram
    n += np.bincount(indices, weights=tmp_w, minlength=bins).astype(ntype)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,) (2,)
```

So I think this is a bug, and you could open a ticket.  You can work around it by passing the number of bins directly:

```
sns.displot(ad, bins=10)
```

or if you really wanted, you could monkeypatch a fix with something like

```
sns.distributions._freedman_diaconis_bins_orig =
    sns.distributions._freedman_diaconis_bins
sns.distributions._freedman_diaconis_bins = lambda x:
    np.round(sns.distributions._freedman_diaconis_bins_orig(x))
```

Comment: FYI this is fixed in current master.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly.
@DSM - Thank you for the answer, it really helped me understand the workings of seaborn. I appreciate your effort very much.